# Combining two data frames and showing their difference - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which will be pulled from CSV files:

```
   X     Value 1  Value 2
0  1     2        1      
1  3     4       -2      
2  3     3        8      
3 -1     4        2      
4  6    -8        2      
5  0     10       1

   X     Value 1  Value 2
0  1     2        1      
1  3     4       -1      
2  3     4        8      
3 -1     4        2      
4  6    -8        2      
5  0     9        1
```

I would like to use Python Pandas to have an output like this, where it would be the second data frame but for any values that have changed there will be a plus/minus in brackets of the amount it has changed by:

```
   X     Value 1  Value 2
0  1     2        1      
1  3     4       -1 (+1)     
2  3     4 (+1)   8      
3 -1     4        2      
4  6    -8        2      
5  0     9 (-1)  1
```

The only thing close to a solution I found online made use of Panels with are deprecated so I want to avoid using them. Also I would like the final output to be a dataframe so that I can apply styles to it.

Comment: Values of column `X` are same in both `Dataframes`? Length of both dataframes is same?

Comment: You example doesn't make sense.  Value 1 from row 5 changed from 10 to 9, why taking 10 with a (+1) sign? Should it be 9 with a (-1) sign? Similarly for Value 1 on row 2, should the sign be (+1)?

Comment: The length and size of the dataframes will always be the same as each other but you could have a set of much larger dataframes and this should still work. Values of column X could also change. Yeah sorry that was a mistake I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the difference between df2 and df1 and create the + or - flag and then append this to df2.

```
df2.astype(str) + \
(df2-df1).applymap(lambda x: ' ({}{})'\
                   .format('+' if x > 0 else '', str(x)).replace('(0)',''))

Out[240]: 
     X Value 1  Value 2
0   1       2        1 
1   3       4   -1 (+1)
2   3   4 (+1)       8 
3  -1       4        2 
4   6      -8        2 
5   0   9 (-1)       1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) first and last  [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) original `df2` converted to `string`s:

- if length of both DataFrames is same
- if values of indexes are same in both `DataFrames`
- if columns names are same in both `DataFrames`

---

```
df = df2.sub(df1).applymap(lambda x: ' ({0:+d})'.format(x) if x != 0 else '')
print (df)
  X Value 1 Value 2
0                  
1              (+1)
2      (+1)        
3                  
4                  
5      (-1) 

df3 = df2.astype(str).add(df)
print (df3)
   X Value 1  Value 2
0  1       2        1
1  3       4  -1 (+1)
2  3  4 (+1)        8
3 -1       4        2
4  6      -8        2
5  0  9 (-1)        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Without formatting skills :

```
(df2.astype(str)+"("+(df2-df1).astype(str)+")").applymap(
lambda s:s.replace("(0)","").replace("(","(+").replace("+-","-"))
```

for :

```
    X Value1  Value2
0   1      2       1
1   3      4  -1(+1)
2   3  4(+1)       8
3  -1      4       2
4   6     -8       2
5   0  9(-1)       1
```